# Error while calling jQuery.show() in Stack Overflow snippet

Tags: discussion, bug, stack-snippets, external-links, error-message

When I'm trying to show using **[`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)** method in jQuery it's always throwing an error in snippet.

> Error:{
>     "message": "Script error.",
>     "filename": "",
>     "lineno": 0,
>     "colno": 0
>   }

[image]

But the same code works in **[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/s951jc4h/)**. I noticed the problem while creating a snippet for my answer. You can check the problem here in this snippet.

```js
$('p').show()
```

```css
p {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>abc</p>
```

**EDIT :** Error in console

> jquery.min.js:3 Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Sandbox access violation: Blocked a frame at "http://stacksnippets.net" from accessing a frame at "null".  Both frames are sandboxed and lack the "allow-same-origin" flag.

Browser : **Chrome Version 50.0.2661.102 (64-bit)**
OS : **Ubuntu 14.04**

Comment: Repro on Chrome 51.0.2704.84 m (64-bit) on Windows 8.1. Looks like there's an error regarding frame communication in a sandboxed environment. You may want to copy and paste the text of that error from your console to the question so it's easier to read/search/etc..

Comment: Works on Firefox 50.

Comment: No-repro on Firefox 50 Win 7,
Repro on Chrome 51.0.2704.84 Win 7

Comment: Repro on IE 11.0.9600.18231 on Windows 8.1 also, with a filename property (in the Error in the console) of "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js".

Comment: Repro Chrome 51 on Linux.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan who still uses IE so you care for that????? IE is only good for one thing, rcognising html versions, run an html script on it, if it doesnt run its HTML 5.

Comment: I love these questions that seem to blur the line between meta and the main site.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that that jQuery's `show` calls `showHide`, which calls `defaultDisplay`.

That function attempts to determine the default display of the element, e.g. `inline` or `block`.

To do that, first it calls `actualDisplay`. That uses [`getDefaultComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/getDefaultComputedStyle) to retrieve the default style. This API is non-standard and only supported by Firefox.

Therefore, other browsers still need a way to know the default display. jQuery uses an iframe:

```
iframe = (iframe || jQuery( "<iframe frameborder='0' width='0' height='0'/>" ))
         .appendTo( doc.documentElement );
doc = iframe[ 0 ].contentDocument;
```

But accessing the `contentDocument` throws on Chrome in a sandboxed iframe.

On Firefox it returns `null`, which would be problematic too.

```js
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
console.log(iframe.contentDocument)
```

The possible solutions seem:

- jQuery checks if `contentDocument` throws or returns `null`.
- Browsers/W3C/WHATWG allow accessing the `contentDocument` of an `iframe` created inside a sandboxed `iframe` without `allow-same-origin` flag.
- Stack Overflow doesn't sandbox stack snippets, or sandboxes them with `allow-same-origin` flag.

Comment: So, jQuery bug basically?

Comment: @Bergi Partially. But I would like to be able to manually access `contentDocument` inside stack snippets. I had found this problem before, I had to use jsfiddle instead.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, here's something weird, the following snippet works fine in Chrome 51 on Windows 8.1:

```js
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('p')).forEach((item) => item.style.display = 'block');
```

```css
p {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>abc</p>
```

Or at least, it did when I copied the OP's snippet into this question and edited it. Now, whether it works later is anyone's guess... [still works after posting].

Note that I don't call any jQuery code, just replicate in plain JavaScript/DOM.

Comment: DId you mean `display = 'block'`?

Comment: @Oriol Oops :). I was trying out a bunch of different ways of replicating... Thanks for catching that.